# how to get OneSignal player id in Cordova and alert that id in mobile app?

Tags: cordova, onesignal

how to get One Signal player id in Cordova and alert that id in mobile app?
also wanted to know how send notification on specific player ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the userId by doing this:
`OneSignal.getUserId()`

To learn more about the getUserId():
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk#user-ids

To learn more about sending push notifications to specific users, please refer to:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#send-to-specific-devices